# Cannot redirect to controller action method using HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(); from non-controller class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I've to redirect to the controller action method from non-controller class.

I am using `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect();`, it is redirecting me to my action method, but it's throwing an error

> "Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent".

```
public void MethodName ()
{    
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

I want to redirect form non-controller class void method.

Comment: that is not work for me

Comment: Use that one Response.Redirect(someUrl)

Comment: i have already try it

Comment: @Jatin Gadhiya i have already try it is not work for me i need to redirect fromnon controller class and  void method

Comment: void method will not return anything how you can redirect to that method. method must be actionresult.

Comment: @Jatin Gadhiya i know that's I have used  HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect() but it is giveng me

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7356294/3852268

Comment: @Jatin i am using event there is not giving me result else can i use routing for that is it work?

Comment: @Parita The tag `Model-View-Controller` is for indicating design pattern question...there is specific tag for `asp.net-mvc`